error <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library
I am trying to use glog in my Visual Studio c++ console app. I used vcpkg to install the library, but I get the following error when compiling:
Error  C1189   #error:  <glog/logging.h> was not included correctly. See the documention for how to consume the library.
I saw folks recommended messing with the CMakeLists.txt file in error "<glog/logging.h> was not included correctly." in including glog in c++ program. But this maybe a noob question...where can I find CMakeLists.txt for a library installed by vcpkg?
Edit: Looks like I am using the non-CMake option on visual studio for vcpkg: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

The answers to the question you found do not mention CMake at all

I mean the accepted answer to the question I linked says add add_definitions(-DGLOG_NO_EXPORT) to CMakeLists.txt right?

Yes, you're right, I didn't scroll that far. But still, #define from the most upvoted answer is C++ only, without any CMake (and does the same thing that add_definitions would do).

Well, I did try the #define option too, but I get a new error: C4996 'google::CustomPrefixCallback': Use PrefixFormatterCallback instead.

For more context, I am trying to use the folly library. I installed it with vcpkg, which also installed glog since its a folly dependency. I don't know whether this is a vcpkg problem, glog problem, or folly problem...if I know, maybe I can ask directly on their github.

The error C4996   'google::CustomPrefixCallback': Use PrefixFormatterCallback instead may be caused by the Visual Studio not following the C++ standard deprecated attribute.
It can be fixed by going to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line and adding /sdl /w34996 .
